# Unknown frame map error(I know I have to be specific but I just don't know what the problem is..)

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, frame, fixed-frame

I am trying to move code (based on ros navigation) from jetson nano to jetson orin. In the jetson I have installed docker and version of ros is noetic both.

the code was successful and able to visualize maps and scans of lidar with jetson nano
But I ported the code to jetson orin nx and ran it ros noetic in docker.

The problem is in jetson orin nx (with docker) cannot find frame map
and it is affecting RobotModel and LaserScan
[image]

This is what happens when I change Global base frame to base_link
[image]
Instead now I have error saying No transform from [map] to [base_link]

I thought CAN network is the problem but CAN signal is coming in fine in both systems
What did I do wrong? What should I test more for this?
Thank you for reading and any suggestion would be great help!

- More that I can't understand..I changed localization algorithm to amcl and it worked fine. It is just als_ros.....

Comment: You'll have to look at the node responsible for publishing the map/odom to base_link transform- how is it configured, what topics is it subscribing to, is it outputting any error messages (or publishing diagnostic messages with errors or warnings)- and update your question with all of that

Comment: it was just that localization package was dying